# Unique approval problem regarding sharepoint workflow

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint

I have a somewhat unique problem regarding sharepoint workflows. There is a situation where a number of users needs to approve a document, which is fine and which I've already accomplished using sequential workflow with replicator activity with a one-user sequence activity inside of it. It works fine and finishes only after all selected users gave their approval on it.
Now the problem gets complicated ten-fold. Certain users can approve the document only after another group of users or one user gave their approval. After that there might be another user or users who will be approving (some in parallel, some sequentially) and maybe another and another. In other words - there is no established scheme or plan of how the approval process will go, it will be created dynamically by a boss-user assigning the approval jobs to users via initiation form (he will have create the scheme dynamically on that form). Does anyone have any ideas on how to accomplish that?